# Repeatedly re-posting a comment to 'bump' an answer

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

On a few questions the same SO user has posted answers or comments. As far as I can tell, each day they are commenting asking me to review their response, and deleting the previous comment - thus causing me to be notified of the new comment.

I think it's the same copy-paste comment every time which makes me wonder if it's even an automated process but I have no way to tell, I don't beleive I can see comment history(?)

Is there any etiquette or rules that apply here? Clearly they want their answers accepted and acepting an answer is the preferred choice *but* since SE has chosen (and the community supports) not to add 'nagging' / reminder functionality for open questions, should individual users be encouraged or discouraged from doing this?

Comment: I'd say that's abusing the notification system and if someone did that to me I'd raise a custom flag since there's no way to ignore/block users in the current system.

Comment: As @ivarni mentions - can you raise a custom flag on a post you know you've had such a comment on and link to this meta post please?

Comment: This specific case has been handled now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comments don't bump anything. However, they do send you an inbox notification, so if you feel that someone is abusing that feature to annoy you, then please do raise a moderator flag (a custom flag on that particular post is most appropriate). Unlike normal users, diamond moderators can see deleted comments, so it's not a problem to figure out what is actually going on.

Comment: "As far as I can tell, each day they are commenting asking me to review their response, and deleting the previous comment - thus causing me to be notified of the new comment."

Comment: I read the question, too, @Zoe!

Comment: I don't see the usefulness of "comments don't bump anything" which is presumably Zoe's point. We all know what 'bump' means

Comment: It's the word you used in your title, @Mr.Boy.

Comment: THis just seems like awkwardness for awkwardness' sake. I ama ware I used the word and I'm aware I put it in quotes.

Comment: @Mr.Boy Instead of abusing a word--especially in a context where it wouldn't be surprising if the writer didn't know what it meant--and putting a word in scare quotes doesn't make clear the idiosyncratic meaning the writer didn't give--why don't you just write what you mean? (Rhetorical.)